# Simulator for iOS 12.0.1 in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

My clients have a problem with my app after updating iOS to 12.0.1. I am trying to test in Xcode (Version 10.1 beta 2 (10O35n)). But all devices in the simulator have 12.1. 
Is that the same thing? How can I test for iOS 12.0.1?

**EDIT**

Is there a way to prevent the app from being installed by users with 12.0.1?

Comment: No, 12.1 is a beta of the next release.  12.0.1 is a small patch of 12.0. You will need a real device with 12.0.1 to test against.

Comment: You can Download iOS Developer Disk Image for XCode. From Here:https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image

Comment: @KetanOdedra Unfortunately there is no image for the 12.0.1 and the 12.0 one is 4 months old.

Comment: like @Paulw11 said 12.0.1 is a small patch of 12.0. You can use 12.1 disk Image.

Comment: @KetanOdedra, Paulw11 I will get an iPhone from one of my colleagues and test against it. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: No, you can't stop 12.0.1 users installing